# Is there a solution to make a method call functions a dynamic amount of parameters by method references?

Tags: java, generics, lambda, java-8

So, I have the following classes:

```
public class MainClass{

    public void run(String infoOne, String infoTwo, String infoThree, String infoFour, String infoFive, String infoSix){        
        SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
        someClass.runSomeMethod();
        someClass.runSomeMethodTwo( infoOne);
        someClass.runSomeMethodThree( infoThree, infoOne, infoSix);
        someClass.runSomeMethodFour( infoTwo, infoFive);
        someClass.runSomeMethodFive(infoThree, infoFive, infoOne, infoSix);
    }
}
```

‌‌

```
public class SomeClass{
    public boolean runSomeMethod(){
        // do something
    }

    public boolean runSomeMethodTwo(String arg){
        // do something
    }

    public boolean runSomeMethodThree(String argOne, String argTwo, String argThree){
        // do something
    }

    public boolean runSomeMethodFour(String argOne, String argTwo){
        // do something
    }

    public boolean runSomeMethodFive(String argOne, String argTwo, String argThree, String argFour){
        // do something
    }
}
```

As you can see it's a bunch of methods taking only Strings as parameters (but a different amount every time). What I want now is to wrap each single method in a try catch block and log some results. To do that I wanted to put a method in between that handles the logging:

```
log(SomeClass::runSomeMethodFour);

public void log(????? method, String...args){
    try{
        if(method.execute(args);
            System.out.println("Success!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to execute!");
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Is this possible in some way? To pass a dynamic number of arguments to a lambda function? Or could I do something with generics?

Comment: If you want to avoid reflection (which is a laudable goal), the only other way I can see to do this is to wrap each method in a helper method which presents a standard argument set.

Comment: Have you considered `runSomeMethod(String[] args)` ?

Comment: @c0der yes, but it kinda goes against my design choices (having no named arguments)

Comment: @c0der in the example above I used stuff as argOne, argTwo, ect. as names of arguments. In my actual application the names do make sense and are part of the overall code design (making it easier to read).

Comment: I don't know if it helps. but you can leave all these methods as they are, and have them call `runSomeMethod(String[] args)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to create a complicated Reflection-based solution. Your problems stem from the unnecessary attempt to separate the method and the parameter arguments, instead of just encapsulating the entire action like

```
public class MainClass {
    public void run(String infoOne, String infoTwo, String infoThree,
                    String infoFour, String infoFive, String infoSix) {        
        SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
        log(() -> someClass.runSomeMethod());
        log(() -> someClass.runSomeMethodTwo(infoOne));
        log(() -> someClass.runSomeMethodThree(infoThree, infoOne, infoSix));
        log(() -> someClass.runSomeMethodFour(infoTwo, infoFive));
        log(() -> someClass.runSomeMethodFive(infoThree, infoFive, infoOne, infoSix));
    }
    public void log(BooleanSupplier method) {
        try {
            if(method.getAsBoolean()) {
                System.out.println("Success!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failed to execute!");
            }
        } catch (Exception e ){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

For the work of the `log` method, only the `boolean` return value is relevant, which matches the functional signature of `BooleanSupplier`.

Comment: Exactly what I need indeed!

Answer (score 2):

[JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.2) described Method Reference Expression:

> The compile-time declaration of a method reference is the method to which the expression refers. In special cases, the compile-time declaration does not actually exist, but is a notional method that represents a class instance creation or an array creation. The choice of compile-time declaration depends on a function type targeted by the expression, just as the compile-time declaration of a method invocation depends on the invocation's arguments.
>
> A method reference expression is compatible in an assignment context, invocation context, or casting context with a target type T if T is a functional interface type (§9.8) and the expression is congruent with the function type of the ground target type derived from T.

the method reference expression must be assign an exactly [Function Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html) at compile time. and Function Interface is a **SAM** Interface. so you can't bind a method handler dynamically by method reference expression at runtime.

but you can using [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html) or [invoke](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/package-summary.html) api to achieve it.

let see each method expression refer to a Function Interface in your `SomeClass` results in refers to different Function Interface type:

```
SomeClass it = new SomeClass();

BooleanSupplier first1 = it::runSomeMethod;//bound
Predicate<SomeClass> first2 = SomeClass::runSomeMethod;//unbound

Predicate<String> second1 = it::runSomeMethodTwo;//bound
BiPredicate<SomeClass, String> second2 = SomeClass::runSomeMethodTwo;//unbound

...
```

Answer (score 1):

Hearing about "reflection" as a comment by [Oliver Charlesworth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/129570/oliver-charlesworth) I came up with the following solution:

```
public class Test {
    static Test testLogger = new Test(); //This should be another class ofcourse, but it doesn't matter for this example

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException{
        Test test = new Test();

        run(test, "something", "hi", "hai", "blaa");
    }

    public static void run(Object pageObjectModel, String methodName, String...arguments){
        Class<String>[] args = new Class[arguments.length];
        Arrays.fill(args, String.class);
        try {
            testLogger.log(pageObjectModel, pageObjectModel.getClass().getMethod(methodName, args), arguments);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void log(Object pageObjectModel, Method method, String...arguments) {
        try {
            if((Boolean)method.invoke(pageObjectModel, (Object[])arguments)){
                System.out.println("Success!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Fail!");
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public boolean something(String one, String two, String three){
        System.out.println(one+", "+two+", "+three);
        return true;
    }
}
```

This seems to be perfect for what I'm trying to achieve. Although I don't really like reflection due to having bad experiences with it (giving problems with obfuscated code) I think it's fine for this project.

Thanks for helping me in the right direction!

Comment: your direction is right! but filtering methods in Class by `arguments` you can use `getDeclaredMethods`/`getMethods`.

Comment: for example: `Stream.of(SomeClass.class.getDeclaredMethods()).filter(accept(methodName,args)).findFirst()`.